# Python : Get Unique Lines between two files

Tags: python-3.x

we have two files and opened it. I am not able to get the unique data.
I tried using intersection as well but that didn't went well

```
Out = open(r'out.txt','r')
processed = open(r'processed.txt',r')
```

In out data is

```
Batch1
Batch2
Batch3
```

In processed data is

```
Batch1
Batch2
```

Now as Batch3 line is unique how i can assign that unique line in a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can read each file into a list, convert each list into a set, then use the set difference:

```
out_set = set([line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('out.txt')])
proc_set = set([line.rstrip('\n') for line in open('processed.txt')])
print(out_set - proc_set)
```

This prints `{'Batch3'}`.